# disable and enable button in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in Items">                          
       <button ng-init="checkIfDisabled[item.name] = true" 
ng-disabled ="checkIfDisabled[item.name] ===true "></button>
                        </div>
```

I have a variable called cart in which I have objects.I want the button to be enabled only if cart variable has that it in any of its objects.

while adding them to cart, I did this:

```
 var itemname = item.name;
  $rootScope.checkIfDisabled[itemname] = false;
```

but this does not seem to work. Is there a work around?

Buttons are initially disabled but not getting enabled when the value changed to false.

Comment: can you show the controller code for checkIfDisabled function?

Comment: CheckIfDisabled is not a function but an object . This object willl have properties with itemnames and values set to true or false depending on cart i.e if cart has that id or name, checkifdisabled[itemname] would be se to false otherwise true. I have added code line in question where I am setting that property to false. but when I check at html end, it is not being changed to false and hence button never gets enabled.

Comment: whell the `$rootScope.checkIfDisabled[itemname] = false;` will never work in controller, you work with scope not rootScope in controller. Try to set it like this: `$scope.checkIfDisabled[itemname] = false;` and for button it is enough just `<button ng-disabled ="checkIfDisabled[item.name] "></button>` to evaluate.

Comment: but rootScope works across across controllers as well than why is it that it would not work? Using it might not be a good idea but it atleast should be working. Isn't it?

Comment: using scope did not help either.

Comment: can you post here the new controller code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to have an array which will hold all the cart items and later you can use conditions to enable/disable them..

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.Items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    $scope.cartItems = [];
    $scope.addToCart = function(item) {
      $scope.cartItems.push(item);
    };
    $scope.doesExist = function(item) {
      return $scope.cartItems.indexOf(item) !== -1;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <button ng-disabled="doesExist(item)" ng-bind="item" ng-click="addToCart(item)"></button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have a checkIfExists function that returns a true or false value depending on if the item exists in cart. items are pushed in cart when some other button is click and I am using checkIfExists in ng-disabled. yet I do not see the button being activated when item is pushed on to the cart

Comment: Worked. While posting it here I noticed that the function was not attached to scope. Thanks a ton :)